# необходимо расширить функцию в коде

Tags: javascript

Вот такой скрипт:

```
let input, random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
         while (input = prompt("Введите число от 0 до 9:")) 

         {
            if (isNaN(input)) alert("Введите число!");


            else if (input > random){
                alert("Меньше!");

            }
            else if (input < random){
                alert("Больше!");

             }
            else if (input == random) {
                alert("Правильно!");
                break;
            }
        }
```

Необходимо сделать три попытки на ответ и отобразить количество оставшихся попыток...

Comment: А что не получается?

Answer (score 0):

думаю как то так.

```js
let input;
let random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
let message = "Введите число от 0 до 9: ";
let attemptsCount = 3;
         while (attemptsCount > 0) {
         input = prompt(`${message} осталось попыток - ${attemptsCount}`)
            attemptsCount = attemptsCount - 1;
            if (isNaN(input)) alert("Введите число!");


            else if (input > random){
                alert("Меньше!");

            }
            else if (input < random){
                alert("Больше!");

             }
            else if (input == random) {
                alert("Правильно!");
                break;
            }
        }
        
        if(attemptsCount === 0 && input != random) {
          alert("У вас не осталось попыток!");
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let input = prompt("Введите число от 0 до 9:", "");
let random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
let attemptsCount = 5;
while (true)
{

    if (attemptsCount == 3) {
        alert("Осталось три попытки");
    }
    else if (attemptsCount == 0) {
        alert("Вы проиграли!");
        break;
    }

    if (isNaN(input)) {
        alert("Введите число!");
        input = prompt("Введите число от 0 до 9:");
        continue;
    }
    else if (input > random) {
        alert("Меньше!");
    }
    else if (input < random) {
        alert("Больше!");
    }
    else if (input == random) {
        alert("Вы выиграли!");
        break;
    }
    input = prompt("Введите число от 0 до 9:");
    --attemptsCount;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10)

ALL: for (var left=3; left; --left) {
  while (1) {
    var input = prompt(`Введите число от 0 до 9:\nосталось ${left} ${left===1 ? "попытка" : "попытки"}`)
    
    if (input == null) break ALL
    if (isNaN(input)) {
      alert("Введите число!")
    } else {
      input = +input
      break
    }
  }

  if (input > random) {
    alert("Меньше!");
  } else if (input < random) {
    alert("Больше!");
  } else if (input == random) {
    alert("Правильно!");
    break;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

На генераторе (ES6+):

```js
const gng = guessNumGen(10); 
let question, 
    input = null; 
while (!(question = gng.next(input)).done)
  input = prompt(question.value); 

function* guessNumGen(max, tries = 3) {
  const num = Math.floor(Math.random() * max), 
        msg = 'Введите число от 0 до 9'; 
  do {
    let answ = yield `${msg} (попыток осталось: ${tries})`; 
    if (answ === null) 
      ++tries; 
    else if ((answ = +answ.trim()) > num)
      alert('Меньше!'); 
    else if (answ < num)
      alert('Больше!'); 
    else if (answ === num)
      return alert('Правильно!'); 
  } while (--tries)
  return alert('Попытки исчерпаны'); 
}
```